# codeigniter submit form using segmented url

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a dropdown form in codeigniter which works fine. When I submit the form I see the URL

```
domain.com/main/search
```

Now I want to pass drink type via segmented url like in below line

```
domain.com/main/search/fanta
```

Could you please help me to do that. Please see below my view:

```
echo form_open("main/search");
$data = array(
"" => "Select Drink",
"cola" =>"cola",
"fanta" =>"fanta",
"sprite" =>"sprite");
echo form_dropdown('drink', $data, set_value('drink'));
echo form_submit("search", "Search");
echo form_close();
```

Comment: downvoting well structured and useful questions is not a good behavior

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is write a script to generate the action dynamically like this

```
$('#select-id').change(function(e){
    var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val(),
    var url   = window.location.href.split('?')[0];

    // have an id to your form
    $("#form-id").attr("action",url + value);

});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. however it shows domain.com/main/search?drink=fanta but I want another url structure like in my question

Comment: is this the only parameter for that particular form??

Comment: but u want only the drink value in url??

Comment: no I will try to do it for checkbox array later.Just wanted to simplify the question to understand how can i pass parameters in url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88254/discussion-between-niranjan-and-educateyourself).